# Source and type of insulation that's safe for gas range oven wrap replacement?

Tags: insulation, oven, stove, range

I have a Kenmore 790.75443411 and they don't have a part number for replacement insulation so it seems I must find some on my own. All I can find that states the dimensions is ceramic fiber that from most of what little I can find isn't safe unless completely sealed due to the fibers getting into the air being on the asbestos level of bad for you. Looking to find a safer type that lists dimensions. I need to go measure it myself but I would estimate the piece needed is about 2"x30"x60" max. The piece I need is the one that wraps around the top over. Someone took the cap off the center burner wile in storage giving mice a way in.

Comment: Superwool is "safe high temperature fiber blanket" (I'm aware of it as I know potters who have chosen to spend more for it rather than have more dangerous stuff like Kaowool around) but ordinary rockwool should be plenty high-temperature for a domestic oven, even on the clean cycles (maybe 750°F - while rockwool is good to about 1900°F)

Comment: The (dubious) health dangers associated with ceramic fiber insulation only manifest *after it has been fired*, i.e., exposed to high temperatures. So, be careful not to breath the fiber-laden dust when removing the old stuff, but no issues when installing the new stuff. With careful handling it is likely that you would not have a concentration of fibers in the air that would present any hazard at all.

Answer (score 1):

**bio-soluble fiber insulation** seems to be the set of keywords most likely to get you non-brand-specific results for safe high temperature blanket insulation. The "bio-soluble" part means it dissolves if it gets into you.

Pottery suppliers and other sources of high-temperature materials will have it.

Rockwool (aka mineral wool or stone wool) (not fiberglass) should cover the temperature range needed for a domestic oven, and is [not classifiable as increasing cancer risk](https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2016-10/documents/fine-mineral-fibers.pdf) per The International Agency for Research on Cancer (according to the linked USA EPA document.)